# How to import package androidhttp, androidjsonfactory,AbstractGoogleClientRequest?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, importerror

> How can i import AbdroidHttp, androidjsonfactory,AbstractGoogleClientRequest packages? I am using Google cloud messaging and code written for register for a device. Getting error package are not exist? Can experts suggest best way to import these packages?

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;

Build Gradle (app) 

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.prasoon.gcmapptest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
//useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: this problem is resolved after addition of  addition of compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.21.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.12.0-beta' in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install target version Google API from SDK manager.